# A binary expects multiple inputs from pipe and pipe is written by Python,why sleep necessary between writes?

Tags: python, c, linux, pipe, stdin

There's a closed source Linux binary which reads inputs from stdin. My goal is to automate sending inputs using Python via a pipe.
I've created named pipe and I run the binary with stdin redirected to this pipe.

My python application writes to this pipe. I need to send the first input data to the binary, receiving this input, the binary updates its state and expects another the second input data. So I send the second input data.

```
f = open(pipe,'w') 
f.write(inputdata1) 
f.flush() 

f.write(inputdata2) 
f.close()
```

The problem is that when I write to the pipe as above the binary gets inputdata1+inputdata2 at single time in its first phase.

Investing the binary with gdb shows that, binary reads the user input via C  library function `read`.

I've tried a lot and have a workaround (may be this is not a workadound but how it should be, but I don't know). Adding a sleep after sending first input data solved my problem. `time.sleep(1)`

My first question is how and why the `time.sleep(1)` makes it work as I've expected. Is it due to the fact that `time.sleep(1)` causes a context switch? Or Do I really need to wait?

My second question is about C library function `read`. Suppose passed count parameter is n, and there are less than n bytes inside pipe and that's all. How and when does read decide to return back to caller? The answer of this may be actually the answer of my problem.

Comment: I am not sure about pipes in python, but when you use them in standard c on linux you have to have both pipe ends closed when finished with writing - the reading and the writing end. I'm also not sure if this is best practice,but for this approach, did you try closing your pipe after your first write, open it up again, writing to it and closing it another time?

Comment: A pipe is a stream of bytes. It does not care about or remember the sizes of the various writes to it—it just appends new data to old. When a reader reads, it gets whatever is available. If you want to organize data into records, it is your job to separate them. You can demarcate records by transmitting their lengths, by setting a fixed length, by marking the ends with a particular byte or sequence of bytes, or other means.

Comment: Does the program print a prompt before each input? If so then you have to use something like expect to automate it.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. 
Trickzter: Now I tried and it worked. But I don't know if it's the best practice or not.
Eric: I got the idea, and keep that in mind. But for this target binary, I don't have possibility to change it.
Dan: I see. It doesn't print any prompt. But i got the idea as well.